# ways to do signature imposition for binding with latex (and specifically the memoir package)

Tags: memoir, pdfpages, signatures, imposition

I've used the memoir package to typeset some shorter pamphlets. Now I am working on a larger booklet that will require signatures, and I'm finding myself a little confused. So much of LaTeX, particularly in the memoir package, is about granular control over the output, and the solutions for producing signatures that I've found so far appear somewhat flawed.

So far I've used:

- for binding without signatures, I've used `memoir`'s stock/trimmed sizing options to produce pdfs that print nicely and work well with stab binding/etc
- for multi signature bindings, I've used [momijizukamori's imposition tool](https://github.com/momijizukamori/bookbinder-js) to convert a single pdf into signatures. It's based on QuantumElephant's bookbinder tool.
- again for multi-signature bindings, I've used [jamis' imposition utility](https://github.com/jamis/impose) (a ruby gem)

Workflow-wise, I prefer the CLI utility of the jamis utility. However, the jamis utility produces more distortion than I want -- it appears to resize the pages to fit even when I've messed with the stock/trim/etc enough that I've basically hardcoded the output pdf page size (from LaTeX)  to be exactly half the stock paper size that I'm going to print the signatures on.

momijizukamori's utility produces the signatures that look the least "weird" or unexpected to my eye. However, I find it still distorts some of my formatting, particularly making my font size look way smaller than it should be. I've been able to work around this, but it's still much more of a Process than it feels like it should be to accomplish this.

The other option that I've heard about but not tried is the LaTeX package [pdfpages](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). This looks like it would be an intermediary step -- create the output pdf from my main.tex, then use `pdfpages` to impose into signatures for printing. However, the package documentation appears to be very focused on the usecase of inserting a single pdf page(s) into a pdf doc, so I wasn't entirely keen on it initially.

Are there other signature imposition solutions that work well with LaTeX documents? It feels very silly and duplicative to angst over precise settings in my main.tex and then have to completely redo them for printing.

Comment: `pdfpages` has a `signature` option. I think you can do a lot, perhaps combining it with `geometry` and `crop` packages.

Comment: And because `pdfpages` provides `signature` [`pdfjam`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfjam) also provides a corresponding option.